# How to rebuild a Windows Image (WIM) using ImageX tool?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, command-line, imagex

I've previouslly mounted a WIM image using DISM where I've removed some packages and then I've unmounted it commiting changes, and now I would like to rebuild the WIM file to save filesize and compression ratio.

I'm trying to follow the specifications of Microsoft help [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749447%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) but I think that I'm using the bad switch of the ImageX command for my intentions...

The command below throws an error saying that the directory name is not valid:

```
ImageX.exe /Check /Compress Maximum /Verify /Capture "C:\WinDVD\Sources\Install.wim" "1" "%UserpProfile%\Desktop\NEW Install.wim"
```

**EDIT:**
Now I've read about the `/Export` switch, but that is what I need? I want to save the full WIM file as is, not only a single image index.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Correct, you need the /Export parameter:

```
Imagex /export C:\WinDVD\Sources\install.wim 1 C:\WinDVD\exported\install.wim /compress maximum
```

(1 is the Index inside the WIM)

Comment: Thanks but if I have for exaple a WIM image that contains two images named "Basic" (Index 1) and other image named "Professional" (Index 2), I can't save/compress/export both images in a single WIM (like the original WIM) using ImageX? then how to really rebuild an entire WIM file?

Comment: Have you tried /Append?

Comment: Investigating I've found in other example that wildcards can be used to mark all index as exportable! so just an `/export "OldImage" "*" "NewImage"` will do the job. thanks.