# Installing windows from cmd to a partition

Tags: windows-7, windows, cmd.exe

I would like to install windows on my computer where I have 3 partitions.

I would like to install it via cmd line on the 3rd partition.

How can I do this?

Comment: its entirely possible to apply a .WIM image to a partition.  Its just that you are asking for trouble when you ultimately do it wrong.  Why can't you boot to the installer and install it normally?  In either way you still have to boot to Windows 7 version of WinPE.

Comment: Did you want to install just once or is your goal an automated revery? In which case read this first:  

http://superuser.com/questions/739735/how-to-rebuild-a-windows-image-wim-using-imagex-tool

Comment: My problem was I've already got windows 10 installed and when I try and run the windows 7 installing on my Macbook pro 2015 it just leaves me with a black screen after getting past the "Windows Installer" from the boot options. I figured installing from CMD would work.